# joomla pagination shows same result on every page

Tags: joomla, pagination

I have page of articles with more than 5 results. 5 results are displayed per page. Pagination shows up. When I go to different pages however, every page has the same 5 results.

My getItems():

```
function getItems()
{   

    $params = $this->getState()->get('params');
    $limit = $this->getState('list.limit');
    // 5

    if ($this->_articles === null && $category = $this->getCategory()) {
        $model = JModel::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
        $model->setState('params', JFactory::getApplication()->getParams());
        $model->setState('filter.category_id', $category->id);
        $model->setState('filter.published', $this->getState('filter.published'));
        $model->setState('filter.access', $this->getState('filter.access'));
        $model->setState('filter.language', $this->getState('filter.language'));
        $model->setState('list.ordering', $this->_buildContentOrderBy());
        $model->setState('list.start', $this->getState('list.start'));
        $model->setState('list.limit', $limit);

        $model->setState('list.direction', $this->getState('list.direction'));
        $model->setState('list.filter', $this->getState('list.filter'));
        // filter.subcategories indicates whether to include articles from subcategories in the list or blog
        $model->setState('filter.subcategories', $this->getState('filter.subcategories'));
        $model->setState('filter.max_category_levels', $this->setState('filter.max_category_levels'));
        $model->setState('list.links', $this->getState('list.links'));


        if ($limit >= 0) {
            $this->_articles = $model->getItems();
            if ($this->_articles === false) {
                $this->setError($model->getError());
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->_articles=array();
        }

        $this->_pagination = $model->getPagination();
    }
    $filterResult = null;


    return $this->_articles;
}
```

My populate state:

```
protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null)
    {
        // Initiliase variables.
        $app    = JFactory::getApplication('site');
        $pk     = JRequest::getInt('id');

        $this->setState('category.id', $pk);

        // Load the parameters. Merge Global and Menu Item params into new object
        $params = $app->getParams();
        $menuParams = new JRegistry;

        if ($menu = $app->getMenu()->getActive()) {
            $menuParams->loadString($menu->params);
        }

        $mergedParams = clone $menuParams;
        $mergedParams->merge($params);

        $this->setState('params', $mergedParams);
        $user       = JFactory::getUser();
                // Create a new query object.
        $db     = $this->getDbo();
        $query  = $db->getQuery(true);
        $groups = implode(',', $user->getAuthorisedViewLevels());

        if ((!$user->authorise('core.edit.state', 'com_content')) &&  (!$user->authorise('core.edit', 'com_content'))){
            // limit to published for people who can't edit or edit.state.
            $this->setState('filter.published', 1);

            /**
             * Custom Author Filter
             */
            if (JRequest::getVar('author')) {
                $this->setState('filter.created_by', $this->getUserId(JRequest::getVar('author')));
            }

            // Filter by start and end dates.
            $nullDate = $db->Quote($db->getNullDate());
            $nowDate = $db->Quote(JFactory::getDate()->toMySQL());

            $query->where('(a.publish_up = ' . $nullDate . ' OR a.publish_up <= ' . $nowDate . ')');
            $query->where('(a.publish_down = ' . $nullDate . ' OR a.publish_down >= ' . $nowDate . ')');

            /**
             * Custom Author Filter
             */
            if (JRequest::getVar('author')) {
                $query->where('(a.created_by = "' . $this->getUserId(JRequest::getVar('author')) . '")');
            }
        }


        // process show_noauth parameter
        if (!$params->get('show_noauth')) {
            $this->setState('filter.access', true);
        }
        else {
            $this->setState('filter.access', false);
        }

        // Optional filter text
        $this->setState('list.filter', JRequest::getString('filter-search'));

        // filter.order
        $itemid = JRequest::getInt('id', 0) . ':' . JRequest::getInt('Itemid', 0);
        $orderCol = $app->getUserStateFromRequest('com_content.category.list.' . $itemid . '.filter_order', 'filter_order', '', 'string');
        if (!in_array($orderCol, $this->filter_fields)) {
            $orderCol = 'a.ordering';
        }
        $this->setState('list.ordering', $orderCol);

        $listOrder = $app->getUserStateFromRequest('com_content.category.list.' . $itemid . '.filter_order_Dir',
            'filter_order_Dir', '', 'cmd');
        if (!in_array(strtoupper($listOrder), array('ASC', 'DESC', ''))) {
            $listOrder = 'ASC';
        }
        $this->setState('list.direction', $listOrder);

        //$this->setState('list.start', JRequest::getVar('limitstart', 0, '', 'int'));

        // set limit for query. If list, use parameter. If blog, add blog parameters for limit.
        if ((JRequest::getCmd('layout') == 'blog') || $params->get('layout_type') == 'blog') {
            $limit = $params->get('num_leading_articles') + $params->get('num_intro_articles') + $params->get('num_links');
            $this->setState('list.links', $params->get('num_links'));
        }
        else {
            $limit = $app->getUserStateFromRequest('com_content.category.list.' . $itemid . '.limit', 'limit', $params->get('display_num'));
        }

        $this->setState('list.limit', $limit);

        // set the depth of the category query based on parameter
        $showSubcategories = $params->get('show_subcategory_content', '0');

        if ($showSubcategories) {
            $this->setState('filter.max_category_levels', $params->get('show_subcategory_content', '1'));
            $this->setState('filter.subcategories', true);
        }



        $this->setState('filter.language',$app->getLanguageFilter());

        $this->setState('layout', JRequest::getCmd('layout'));

    }
```

My display function de view.html.php

```
function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $app    = JFactory::getApplication();
        $user   = JFactory::getUser();

        // Get some data from the models
        $state      = $this->get('State');

        $params     = $state->params;
        $items      = $this->get('Items');

        $contactId = JRequest::getVar('author');
        if($contactId){
            $this->setUserId($contactId);
            $this->setContactName($this->userId);
        }

        $category   = $this->get('Category');
        $children   = $this->get('Children');
        $parent     = $this->get('Parent');
        $pagination = $this->get('Pagination');


        // Check for errors.
        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) {
            JError::raiseError(500, implode("\n", $errors));
            return false;
        }

        if ($category == false) {
            return JError::raiseError(404, JText::_('JGLOBAL_CATEGORY_NOT_FOUND'));
        }

        if ($parent == false) {
            return JError::raiseError(404, JText::_('JGLOBAL_CATEGORY_NOT_FOUND'));
        }

        // Setup the category parameters.
        $cparams = $category->getParams();
        $category->params = clone($params);
        $category->params->merge($cparams);

        // Check whether category access level allows access.
        $user   = JFactory::getUser();
        $groups = $user->getAuthorisedViewLevels();
        if (!in_array($category->access, $groups)) {
            return JError::raiseError(403, JText::_("JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR"));
        }

        // PREPARE THE DATA
        // Get the metrics for the structural page layout.
        $numLeading = $params->def('num_leading_articles', 1);
        $numIntro   = $params->def('num_intro_articles', 4);
        $numLinks   = $params->def('num_links', 4);

        // Compute the article slugs and prepare introtext (runs content plugins).

        for ($i = 0, $n = count($items); $i < $n; $i++)
        {
            $item = &$items[$i];
            $item->slug = $item->alias ? ($item->id . ':' . $item->alias) : $item->id;

            // No link for ROOT category
            if ($item->parent_alias == 'root') {
                $item->parent_slug = null;
            }

            $item->event = new stdClass();

            $dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();

            // Ignore content plugins on links.
            if ($i < $numLeading + $numIntro) {
                $item->introtext = JHtml::_('content.prepare', $item->introtext);

                $results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentAfterTitle', array('com_content.article', &$item, &$item->params, 0));
                $item->event->afterDisplayTitle = trim(implode("\n", $results));

                $results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentBeforeDisplay', array('com_content.article', &$item, &$item->params, 0));
                $item->event->beforeDisplayContent = trim(implode("\n", $results));

                $results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentAfterDisplay', array('com_content.article', &$item, &$item->params, 0));
                $item->event->afterDisplayContent = trim(implode("\n", $results));
            }
        }

        // Check for layout override only if this is not the active menu item
        // If it is the active menu item, then the view and category id will match

        $active = $app->getMenu()->getActive();

        if ((!$active) || ((strpos($active->link, 'view=category') === false) || (strpos($active->link, '&id=' . (string) $category->id) === false))) {
            // Get the layout from the merged category params
            if ($layout = $category->params->get('category_layout')) {
                $this->setLayout($layout);
            }
        }
        // At this point, we are in a menu item, so we don't override the layout
        elseif (isset($active->query['layout'])) {
            // We need to set the layout from the query in case this is an alternative menu item (with an alternative layout)
            $this->setLayout($active->query['layout']);
        }

        // For blog layouts, preprocess the breakdown of leading, intro and linked articles.
        // This makes it much easier for the designer to just interrogate the arrays.
        if (($params->get('layout_type') == 'blog') || ($this->getLayout() == 'blog')) {
            $max = count($items);

            // The first group is the leading articles.
            $limit = $numLeading;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $limit && $i < $max; $i++) {
                $this->lead_items[$i] = &$items[$i];
            }

            // The second group is the intro articles.
            $limit = $numLeading + $numIntro;
            // Order articles across, then down (or single column mode)
            for ($i = $numLeading; $i < $limit && $i < $max; $i++) {
                $this->intro_items[$i] = &$items[$i];
            }

            $this->columns = max(1, $params->def('num_columns', 1));
            $order = $params->def('multi_column_order', 1);

            if ($order == 0 && $this->columns > 1) {
                // call order down helper
                $this->intro_items = ContentHelperQuery::orderDownColumns($this->intro_items, $this->columns);
            }

            $limit = $numLeading + $numIntro + $numLinks;
            // The remainder are the links.
            for ($i = $numLeading + $numIntro; $i < $limit && $i < $max;$i++)
            {
                    $this->link_items[$i] = &$items[$i];
            }
        }

        $children = array($category->id => $children);

        //Escape strings for HTML output
        $this->pageclass_sfx = htmlspecialchars($params->get('pageclass_sfx'));


        $this->assign('maxLevel', $params->get('maxLevel', -1));
        $this->assignRef('state', $state);
        $this->assignRef('items', $items);
        $this->assignRef('category', $category);
        $this->assignRef('children', $children);
        $this->assignRef('params', $params);
        $this->assignRef('parent', $parent);
        $this->assignRef('pagination', $pagination);
        $this->assignRef('user', $user);
        $this->_prepareDocument();
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
```

If i print the contents of $pagination in the view.html.php here:

```
$this->_prepareDocument();

        echo '<pre>'; print_r($pagination); exit(); 
        parent::display($tpl);
```

I get the following results:

In my template file I echo the pagination:

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks(); ?>
```

By the way, clicking on 'next' does change the url into `...?start=5`.

Comment: Make a `==` to `$category = $this->getCategory()` also can you post your `getListQuery()`?

Comment: Which core Joomla model class are you extending?  JModelList?

Answer (score 0):

This line in `populateState` is commented out

```
$this->setState('list.start', JRequest::getVar('limitstart', 0, '', 'int'));
```

Uncomment it change it tot get the "start" parameter:

```
$this->setState('list.start', JRequest::getVar('start', 0, '', 'int'));
```